# What's In Your Pocket?

Tags: knowledge, optimization

You have in your pocket a set of U.S. coins.<sup>1</sup>
Using these coins you can count out a face-value total<sup>2</sup> of exactly $96¢$, $97¢$, $98¢$, or $99¢$, using exactly the minimum number of coins possible for each of those respective amounts.
Moreover, you have only the minimum number of coins in your pocket for which the above is possible.

> - **How many coins are in your pocket?**
> - **What denominations are they?**
> - **With what minimal set of these coins can you count out exactly 96¢?**
> - **With what minimal set of these coins can you count out exactly 97¢?**
> - **With what minimal set of these coins can you count out exactly 98¢?**
> - **With what minimal set of these coins can you count out exactly 99¢?**

<sub><sup>1</sup> Limited to real, circulated currency coins issued by the United States Mint.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Mis-struck, old, or otherwise rare coins may be more valuable than the coin's stated face value;

    for this puzzle we ignore this, and only use the stated face values of the coins when determining "value".</sub>

Comment: For those not from the U.S. (such as myself), what are the possible values of U.S. coins?

Comment: [here's a list](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/5e/25/ab/5e25ab1de838db0b479441a4beb00520.jpg)

Comment: You also have 1$ coin (not that it is of any help here).

Comment: Amazing. 5 people so far have found this puzzle good enough to answer but not good enough to ^vote while at it.

Comment: @humn Why should people upvote just because they leave an answer?

Comment: If a question isn't worthy of a vote, wouldn't an answer presumably add to the clutter?

Comment: @humn: Whether or not a question is good largely depends on its answer; you're asking for a verdict based on incomplete information.

Comment: @humn I answered it because I found the solution. I did not upvote because I felt the question itself was mediocre. I don't see how answers to mediocre puzzles, even if not *good*, are simply "clutter".

Comment: @Volatility `:(`

Comment: Ok, it's probably time to let the voting discussion go, or move it elsewhere. This isn't an appropriate place to sound off on community voting behavior. Please move along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we interpret

> "circulated currency" as "in circulation at some point in time, not necessarily now",

then we can have

> 6 coins: 50c, 25c, [20c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-cent_piece_(United_States_coin)), [3c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-cent_silver), [2c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-cent_piece_(United_States)), and a 1c.

Using these, you can get the appropriate values by

> counting the 50c, 25c, and 20c pieces, and then
>  - 1c for 96c
>  - 2c for 97c
>  - 3c for 98c
>  - 3c and 1c for 99c

which adheres to the rule that each of the values can be made by the minimum number of coins.

Comment: Oh man that list of U.S. coins from @Beastly Gerbil threw me off. Good find tho.

Answer (score 1):

From the set of coins

> {4x 1c, 2x 10c, 1x 25c, 1x 50c}

you can get

> (2x10+25+50)c=95c

So adding up the required number of 1c coin(s) will give you 96c, 97c, 98c, and 99c. These are optimal.

Comment: *Not* optimal; you can do better than this.

Comment: So it is a trick question then :(. I am deeply disappointed.

Comment: There is more to it than the glaringly obvious, or it wouldn't be worth asking.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you concur with the claim that to get 99c, you need to use *at least* 8 coins (4+2*10+25+50)?

Comment: Because of the nature of this puzzle I'm giving no hints or comments beyond what I have, until and unless a proper hint is needed after a suitable interval of not being solved, or until I accept an answer.

Comment: So it is a trick question then!

Comment: Expect votes for an answer to a puzzle you didn't vote on?

Comment: @humn just cause you answer a puzzle, doesn't mean you have to upvote it. It might be a rubbish puzzle! (Not saying this one is)

Comment: @humn, fair point. I firmly believe in the principle, that users vote for whatever reasons. I might vote up a post on sunny days, otherwise I might just leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

More of a lateral-thinking approach:

> [image]
>  Where the minus is created from any coin put on its edge and number of pennies is 1, 2, 3 or 4.

So we use

> 6 coins: 1 dollar, 4x 1 cent and 1 any coin

Comment: [tag:lateral-thinking] is quite deliberately absent here.  Sorry.